# how to place inner text to a same multiple td at once using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm still learning JS, how to place inner text to a same multiple td at once using JavaScript ?
I'm trying to place "working Time" to multiple td element that have same id name which is "cellWork" but in my input it doesn't show :S why ?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the `[<>]` snippet editor. Post CODE, not PICTURES of code

Comment: Change id to class. IDs need to be unique. Then do 
`const yesChecked = yes.checked; document.querySelectorAll(".cellWork").forEach(cell => cell.innerText = yesChecked ? "working time" : "free time");`

Comment: mpliungjan , YOU SAVED MY LIFE DUDE YOU ARE THE BEST <3